# In an Elisp regexp, does anchor `^` not work with new line in front?

Tags: regular-expressions, newlines

In an Elisp regexp, when I want to specify a pattern across two consecutive lines, I found that `^J^.*` (`^J` is new line, and `^` is anchor of the beginning of a line) doesn't work,  but `^J.*` works. I was wondering why? (Is it also the case in other flavor of regex, such as the one used in Python?)

Comment: There's confusion in the way your question is written. Presumably, when you wrote `^J` you meant the single character Control-J (aka newline), and not the two characters `^` and `J`. But when you wrote `^.*` I'm guessing you meant the three characters `^`, `.`, and `*`.

Comment: Please one question per question. Also, please do not ask Python questions on Emacs  SE: SO is the proper place.

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be found in the [Gnu Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html):

> `^` is a special character that matches the empty string, but only at the beginning of a line in the text being matched [...]
>
> For historical compatibility reasons, `^` can be used with this meaning **only at the beginning of the regular expression, or after `\(` or `\|`**.

Comment: thanks. Is it also the case in other implementations of the same flavor as in Emacs, and in implementations of other flavors of regex, such as the one used in Python?

Comment: Please do not ask additional questions in comments. Ask a new question - except that in this case, the question is way too general. You can ask the particular question about the Python regex engine on SO, but otherwise, the question is too open-ended as it stands.